# word before compound sentence

Tags: sentence

Jumping straight to an example:

あなたはずっと大切で忘れない

Does the ずっと belong only to 大切？ Or does it also belong to 忘れない?
In other words, does the sentence mean "You are forever precious and I'll never forget you" or does it mean "You are forever precious and I will not forget you"?

Comment: What do you mean "belong to"? Do you mean to ask which word it modifies?

Comment: @EddieKal Exactly

Comment: In your example, is there any significant difference between "I will never forget you" and "I will not forget you"? I feel that "I will not forget you" has the same permanence, and adding "never" is only for flourish. If we can agree on that, then I'd have to say that ずっと only modifies 大切 because they could also add another word for flourish (i.e. ずっと大切で永遠に忘れない).